# How unload an extension when i cant login in the backend and the install tool is gone

Tags: typo3-9.x

when upgrading from TYPO3 8.7 to 9.5 i got this error message in the install tool :

Something went wrong. Please use Check for broken extensions to see if a loaded extension breaks this part of the install tool and unload it.

The box below may additionally reveal further details on what went wrong depending on your debug settings. It may help to temporarily switch to debug mode using Settings > Configuration Presets > Debug settings.

If this error happens at an early state and no full exception back trace is shown, it may also help to manually increase debugging output in typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php:['BE']['debug'] => true, ['SYS']['devIPmask'] => '*', ['SYS']['displayErrors'] => 1,['SYS']['systemLogLevel'] => 0, ['SYS']['exceptionalErrors'] => 12290

Now i am lost because i dont know how to unload an extension ... 
- i cant login in the backend
- the install tool is gone - no possibility to get it running again
- typo3conf/autoload is deleted
- typo3temp is deleted
- and in packagestate there is no possibility to unload an extension
I even emptied the complete extension folder but nothing changes.

How is it possible to unload a extension in TYPO3 9 and get the install tool running? Why does it break?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use the command line with

```sh
vendor/bin/typo3 extension:deactivate <EXT-KEY>
```

or delete the array entry for your extension in the file `public/typo3conf/PackageStates.php`. In both cases, you may need to also clear `public/typo3temp/var` manually.

Comment: attractive answer but I cannot find any 'public' directory anywhere ... neither know how to setup the command line to accept this command ... also directory 'vendor' is not reachable in this tool ...

Comment: @webMan Are you sure, you are running a TYPO3 v9.5?